# Removing DATABASE_URL config var crashing my previously working heroku website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Here's the story, my heroku site was originally using the 5mb shared postgres db with no problems. I had a valid `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` and no `DATABASE_URL`

Then I added a config var by doing

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=non_existing_database_just_for_fun
```

Just to see if it would switch from the shared db to this new one I just set. It did just that, and promptly crashed my app as expected since no valid database was found.

Then I did `heroku config:remove DATABASE_URL` hoping to get my site back to normal. But now it keeps crashing and never succeeds in starting up. If I do a `heroku config` I see that I still have a valid `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` and no `DATABASE_URL` but the site still wont work.

I did get it working by setting up `DATABASE_URL` to match `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` but I'd like to get it back to how things were originally, the site working without needing `DATABASE_URL`. Any ideas no how I can get things back to the way they were short of having to reinstall my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATABASE_URL` is the key that Heroku expect you to use for your database connectivity.  They will not touch this value unless you ask them to (aside from initial setup).

The `SHARED_DATABASE_URL` is the URL of the shared database that they have provided to you.

By default, Heroku set your `DATABASE_URL` to match your `SHARED_DATABASE_URL`.

I'm not entirely sure why would would want your application to not have a `DATABASE_URL`, as that's what's used.  If you look at the [bottom of this](http://neilmiddleton.com/sharing-databases-between-heroku-applications/), you can see what they do with your `config/database.yml` and how it affects your application.

Comment: Dang it, my assumption that I didn't originally have a DATABASE_URL was wrong (verified by creating a new app)! I do that all the time, make wrong assumptions :( Anyway, thanks for this.